# How to target and change this label in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, label

So this is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="modal-title"><label>Band</label>: Select one or more genres below</div>
```

If I just want to target that div (Which is inside of a div with the ID of #modal-1) and replace the content of the label, and not rewrite all the HTML. How would I do so?

What I've tried with no luck

```
$('#'+modal_ID '.modal-title').attr(label);
```

and it breaks my functionality

Comment: you need a space  like this : `$("#"+modal_ID+" .modal-title")`

Comment: Ah thanks for that! Combined with Blake's answer I got the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is not an attribute but an element inside of the `.modal-title` `div` You need to get the element in your selector and change the text of the label to your desired label text. Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/uLUJZ/)

```
$('#'+modal_ID+' .modal-title > label').text(label);
           // ^ you were missing the extra + symbol
```

Comment: Sweet thanks! And thanks for taking the time to write out a fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may do the trick

```
$('#modal-1 .modal-title label').html(label);
```

Not sure what `modal_ID`, if required, your code would look like this

```
$('#' + modal_ID + ' .modal-title label').html(label);
```

Comment: I think you also need a '+' after modal-ID?